# monacaのconsole.logでの制限字数？

Tags: monaca

monacaで最近作成していたプロジェクトのcordovaを4から5.2に変更したところ、
console.log()でこれまで引数の内容がすべてログに出力されていたのが、
変更してからログの内容が途中で区切られてそれ以降が出力されないようになりました。

設定か何かがあるのかと探したのですが見つかりませんでしたが
この現象についてご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示ください。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 自己解決しました。
console.log()の引数に「,（半角カンマ）」が含まれていると
そこで出力が区切られてしまうようです。

なので            
console.log("出力したい文字列".replace(/,/g,"､"));
で、とりあえずすべて出力されるようになりました。

monacaの設定なのかわかりませんが、かなり迷惑な話でした…。

Answer (score 3):

自己解決の追記です。

console.log("出力したい文字".replace(/,/g,"､").replace(/[/g,"【").replace(/]/g,"】"));

で解決しました。

,（半角カンマ）、［、］(半角カギカッコ？)
の３種類が悪さをしていたようなのでreplaceで適当に変換しました。

単なるmonacaの設定なのかは区別がつきませんでしたが、とりあえず上記で解決です。
お騒がせしました。